# Bottle.py server sometimes refusing connections, or giving 404, even when route exists

Tags: python, bottle

Im having some issues with my Bottle server, which at this point is little more than a basic account management service. It worked fine when I was on my own machine, but when I uploaded it to my VPS it just doesnt want to work. When I try to access routes (for example `/acc/`), it sometimes either gives a 404 not found error, or a connection refused error, or actually works.

I did move from windows to ubuntu 16.04 (my machine to vps), I dont know if thats relevant.

You can view my full python code here: https://pastebin.com/SDUhQ92X

However, this is a minimal version with all the routes except one removed:

```py
#import shelve
#import json
from bottle import route, run, static_file
#from createuser import create_user

@route('/acc/')
def server_static():
    return static_file('home.html', r'/lemonde/accountmanagement')

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I dont get any error messages in console, just 404 when it doesnt work.

Its live for you to see at `158.69.185:80/acc` if you want to check yourself.

Comment: The bottle.py server is not intended to be run as a real web server. It's for development only. You need to run your application in a real WSGI server like Gunicorn or uWSGI.

Comment: The route `/acc` is not the same as `/acc/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the fact that `/acc` is not the save as `/acc/`, which was suggested by @Jonathon Reinhart